# Running C# Console Application on Dreamweaver

Tags: c#

I have transferred a C# program to my school computer, but I don't have Visual Studio and I can't download it. How do I run it on Dreamweaver? As that is the program that comes up when I run it.

Comment: can you please elaborate? what have you transferred onto the school computer? compiled binaries or source code? and can you please define "Run it" do you mean open up the code to edit it or execute an executable?

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  DreamWeaver is not for compiling C# console applications.  It can be used for developing ASP.NET pages, which is why it could open a C# file.

Comment: I Dont feel you can sufficiently answer the question with the provided info. Any answer would be based on assumptions from the op's question.

Comment: Well, the title says "running C# Console Application".  I feel that I am not making an assumption.  To run it, you have a compile it.

Comment: You are assuming the OP is using the same definition of Run as you are. Run also does not assume compilation in the strict sense of the word ;)

Comment: You are correct.  The OP did say "run", but since it opened in DreamWeaver, in all likelihood, the OP was clicking on the source file (*.cs) which would open in DreamWeaver, if no other programs were set to open that file type.

Comment: "in all likelihood" and there lies the 2nd assumption

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about opening and editing the source code, or do you have a compiled application? In either case Dreamweaver will be no use to you. You can edit source code in any text editor but you will need to compile it somehow. If you can't use Visual Studio have a look at Sharpdevelop - this can be run as a portable app from a flash drive.